# Styling a form wizard

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to code something like the below in HTML5 and CSS3?

[image: form wizard]

I can do the circles with the numbers inside them nicely, but I don't know how to go about the line/road connecting the steps?

Markup I have in mind is:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>1</span></li>
    <li><span>2</span></li>
    <li><span>3</span></li>
    <li><span>4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: working demo http://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sVVY/3).

[image: Example]

### HTML

Rather than wrapping the numbers within `span` elements, I've simply used the following markup:

```
<ul class="steps">
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li class="active">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

I've then made use of the `:before` pseudo-element to insert that line before every `li` apart from the very first one:

### CSS

```css
ul.steps {
    background: tomato;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

ul.steps li {
    border-radius: 42%;
    background: #DB4024;
    color: #FFB3B3;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-right: 53px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32px;
}

ul.steps li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

ul.steps li:before {
    background: #DB4024;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    right: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    width: 59px;
}

ul.steps li:first-child:before {
    display: none;
}
```

I've then given it the `.active` style (making the background white and the colour black):

```css
ul.steps li.active, ul.steps li.active:before {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
```

#### Notes:

1. In this example I've used fixed width values. The `ul` and `li` widths and the `li` margins and position offsets will need to be adjusted by you accordingly.
2. `class="active"` will need to be added to all highlighted `li` elements, not just the current one.
3. The `li` elements are not perfect circles due to the line having to meet them on a flat edge.

Comment: damn you, for having posted such a nice answer ;D

Comment: At the edge, when the line meets the circle .. why aren't they touching by 1px? :(

Comment: That's caused by the radius. It's not meeting a flat surface. Changing the `border-radius` from `100%` to `42%` fixes this, but the `li` elements are no longer perfect circles: http://jsfiddle.net/8sVVY/3/. **Edit:** I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to solve such a problem:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2z2QA/

CSS:

```
ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
}

ul li span
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color: lightgreen;
}

ul li.done span,
ul li.active  span
{
    background-color: silver;
    color: gray;
}

ul li.done:after
{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    right:-10px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2.5px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="done"><span>1</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span>2</span></li>
    <li><span>3</span></li>
    <li><span>4</span></li>
</ul>
```